# I can not show my product feature image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_type' => 'product'
);

$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);

if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-sm-4 nk">   
            <div class="course">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));  ?>" />
                </a>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <h5><?php the_author(); ?></h5>
                <p><?php echo $product->get_rating_html();?></p>
                <h4><?php echo $product->get_price_html();?></h4>
            </div>
      </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
    <p>
        <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: To add featured image support in a WordPress theme, you need to add this line of code in your theme’s functions.php file:
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,
replace this code

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));  ?>" />
```

with

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));  ?>
```

And you need to add `<?php global $product; ?>` exactly before it use.
The total correct code is

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_type' => 'product'
);

$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);

if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php global $product;?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 nk">   
            <div class="course">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));  ?>
                </a>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <h5><?php the_author(); ?></h5>
                <p><?php echo $product->get_rating_html();?></p>
                <h4><?php echo $product->get_price_html();?></h4>
            </div>
      </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
    <p>
        <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing mistake whenever you use `the_post_thumbnail()` write with echo `the_post_thumbnail();`

so instead of `the_post_thumbnail()` use `echo the_post_thumbnail()`